# TouchBarButton is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, electron

using electron I get the following error: https://hastebin.com/veguxupeka.apache

Here is my code, this code is a better discord add-on, in javascript. I am still somewhat new to JS, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

```js
//META{"name":"BetterTouchbar"}*//
const { app, BrowserWindow, TouchBar, TouchBarButton} = require('electron');
class BetterTouchbar {

    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        this.initialized = false;
    }

    // Meta
    getName() { return "BetterTouchbar"; }
    getShortName() { return "BT"; }
    getDescription() { return "eekZ"; }
    getVersion() { return "0.1.0"; }
    getAuthor() { return "Aj3douglas"; }

    start(){

        const button = new TouchBarButton({
            label: "a",
            backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
            accessibilityLabel: "a",
            click: ()=>{
                console.log("Clicked a button")
            }
        });
        const touchBar = new TouchBar({
            items: [button],
        })
        window.setTouchBar(touchBar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you import `TouchBarButton`. It's `undefined` when your code executes and that's why you see this error.

Extract it from `TouchBar` like this:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, TouchBar } = require('electron');
const { TouchBarButton } = TouchBar;
```

**Edit:**

After reading your question again, what you're looking for is to modify a core feature of Discord, which is not made possible by the plugin system, so you need to override the Discord code. If Discord was open source you could fork it and modify the code base, but it isn't, so you cannot do that.

Comment: I did try this, however that throws the following error
"Cannot destructure property 'TouchBarButton' of 'TouchBar' as it is undefined."

Comment: That means `TouchBar` is `undefined` as well

Comment: How is it undefined in the above scenario? Should the line above not define it? Someone mentioned that electron may not be included in discord, whilst discord does use electron, and that I may need to inject the npm package, however I have no idea how to do so

Comment: Yes it should, did you properly `npm install electron`?

Comment: I did, control clicking on the TouchBar actually takes me to the TouchBar class, so I think I did that correctly

Comment: If you try to override the Electron code of Discord, I doubt this is possible. I think that you should only use the API provided by Discord.

Comment: So what's my best bet to do from here? I really need to be able to access this;

Comment: Sorry but this is impossible, I've edited my answer to explain.

Comment: Theres gotta be a way somehow... All I need to do is edit the Touch Bar on Macbook pros

Comment: Your better chance is to edit the compiled code which is pretty hacky and should be quite difficult and not maintainable.